# Swift - C function and struct tm

Tags: swift

I have Swift program, that uses C API. One of my API method returns `struct tm`. Is there a way, how to convert it to Swift Date or I have to parse it myself on C side and pass parts manually to Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in function in the Swift standard library. But you can use `timegm()` from the C library as described in [C: Converting struct tm times with timezone to time_t](http://kbyanc.blogspot.de/2007/06/c-converting-struct-tm-times-with.html):

```
extension Date {
    init?(tm: tm) {
        let gmtOffset = tm.tm_gmtoff // Save the offset because timegm() modifies it
        var tm = tm // A mutable copy
        var time = timegm(&tm) // The time components interpreted as GMT
        if time == -1 { return nil } // timegm() had an error
        time -= gmtOffset // Adjustment for actual time zone
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(time))
    }
}
```

which can then be used as

```
if let date = Date(tm: yourStructTmVariable) {
    print(date)
} else {
    print("invalid value")
}
```

Another possible approach is to fill a `DateComponents` struct with
the values from `struct tm` and use `Calendar` to convert it to
a `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    init?(tm: tm) {
        let comps = DateComponents(year: 1900 + Int(tm.tm_year),
                                   month: 1 + Int(tm.tm_mon),
                                   day: Int(tm.tm_mday),
                                   hour: Int(tm.tm_hour),
                                   minute: Int(tm.tm_min),
                                   second: Int(tm.tm_sec))
        var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: tm.tm_gmtoff) else { return nil }
        cal.timeZone = tz
        guard let date = cal.date(from: comps) else { return nil }
        self = date
    }
}
```